# JWPlayer not running in iPhone and iPod

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipod, video-player

I am using following code for using to play my video in **JWPlayer**

My testing link - http://ofd13126.com/video/

Code:

```
<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="877" height="500">
    <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=feasible-study.flv" />
       <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" autostart="true"
              id="player2"
              name="player2"
              src="player.swf"
              width="877" 
              height="500"
              allowscriptaccess="always" 
              allowfullscreen="true"
              flashvars="file=feasible-study.flv" />
</object>
```

The above code is working in desktop and all of the browsers, but it is not working in iPhone and iPod.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to play a flash video and iOS doesnt support flash, try to use a format that iOS supports.